# xarray: wrong time after saving

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray, netcdf4

Can anybody reproduce this behavior of xarray when saving times with large values? I'm a bit at a loss as to what is happening here.

Edit: It seems xarray is doing something wrong if the numeric value of "time" exceeds a certain threshold. Note that this does only occur for "days since" and not, e.g., for "seconds since".

I'm am using Python 3 and xarray version 0.10.7.

```python
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# print('xarray version: {}'.format(xr.__version__))

ds = xr.Dataset(coords={'time': (
    'time', 
    np.arange(106300.5, 106665.5+5*365, 365), 
    {'units': 'days since 1800-01-01 00:00:00'})})
# print(ds.time)
ds = xr.decode_cf(ds)
# print(ds.time)
ds.to_netcdf('./test.nc')
ds = xr.open_dataset('./test.nc', decode_cf=False)
print(ds.time)
```

Out:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 6)>
array([ 106300.5     ,  106665.5     , -106473.482335, -106108.482335,
       -105743.482335, -105378.482335])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) float64 1.063e+05 1.067e+05 -1.065e+05 -1.061e+05 ...
Attributes:
    _FillValue:  nan
    units:       days since 1800-01-01
    calendar:    proleptic_gregorian
```

Edit: Here is the is the file content with ncdump:

```
netcdf test {
dimensions:
    time = 6 ;
variables:
    double time(time) ;
        time:_FillValue = NaN ;
        time:units = "days since 1800-01-01" ;
        time:calendar = "proleptic_gregorian" ;

// global attributes:
        :_NCProperties = "version=1|netcdflibversion=4.4.1.1|hdf5libversion=1.10.1" ;
data:

 time = 106300.5, 106665.5, -106473.482334601, -106108.482334601, 
    -105743.482334601, -105378.482334601 ;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the negative time representing floats?
What is the contents of `test.nc` file?

Comment: This has been fixed in version 0.11.0 via [#2519](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/pull/2519)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I can reproduce this.  This could be considered a bug in xarray; you might consider raising an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues).

When saving the file, under the hood xarray is taking the decoded dates and converting them to timedeltas since a reference date.  The issue is that the dates in your example dataset straddle the borderline of being 292 years later than the reference date provided (1800-01-01).

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import xarray as xr

In [3]: ds = xr.Dataset(coords={'time': (
   ...:     'time',
   ...:     np.arange(106300.5, 106665.5+5*365, 365),
   ...:     {'units': 'days since 1800-01-01 00:00:00'})})
   ...:

In [4]: ds = xr.decode_cf(ds)

In [5]: ds.time
Out[5]:
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 6)>
array(['2091-01-15T12:00:00.000000000', '2092-01-15T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2093-01-14T12:00:00.000000000', '2094-01-14T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2095-01-14T12:00:00.000000000', '2096-01-14T12:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2091-01-15T12:00:00 2092-01-15T12:00:00 ...

In [6]: ds.to_netcdf('so.nc')

In [7]: xr.open_dataset('so.nc', decode_times=False).time
so.nc
Out[7]:
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 6)>
array([ 106300.5     ,  106665.5     , -106473.482335, -106108.482335,
       -105743.482335, -105378.482335])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) float64 1.063e+05 1.067e+05 -1.065e+05 -1.061e+05 ...
Attributes:
    units:     days since 1800-01-01
    calendar:  proleptic_gregorian
```

292 years is the maximum length of time a `np.timedelta64` object with nanosecond precision can represent (see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units) in the documentation); any more than that and you will run into overflow (which is the cause of the negative values).

A workaround you could use is to overwrite the units encoding associated with the times in your dataset with a new value:

```
In [8]: ds.time.encoding['units'] = 'days since 1970-01-01'

In [9]: ds.to_netcdf('so-workaround.nc')

In [10]: xr.open_dataset('so-workaround.nc', decode_times=False).time
Out[10]:
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 6)>
array([44209.5, 44574.5, 44939.5, 45304.5, 45669.5, 46034.5])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) float64 4.421e+04 4.457e+04 4.494e+04 4.53e+04 4.567e+04 ...
Attributes:
    units:     days since 1970-01-01
    calendar:  proleptic_gregorian
```

Here I have chosen `'days since 1970-01-01'` intentionally, since this is what `np.datetime64` objects are centered around in NumPy.

Comment: Thanks for checking @skc! I looked into it a bit more and filed a report [here](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2272).